Fine tune Llama 2 model with custom dataset but getting zero training loss and validation loss
My problem is that the output of training loss and validation loss is 0 for the 3 epoch
Here I am using kaggle notebook
!pip install transformers datasets torch bitsandbytes peft accelerate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/open-domain/open domain - Copy.csv')

Focus on text and label columns
df = df[['text', 'class']]

Display the first few rows of the dataset
print(df.head())
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login() 

convert to Hugging Face Dataset
from datasets import Dataset

Rename columns to match Hugging Face's expected format
#dataset = dataset.rename_column('text', 'text')
#dataset = dataset.rename_column('class', 'label')

Ensure the columns are correctly named
df = df.rename(columns={'class': 'label'}) 
Check for any missing values
print("is null:",df.isnull().sum())

Convert text labels to numeric
df['label'] = df['label'].astype('category').cat.codes

Convert pandas DataFrame to Hugging Face Dataset
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
Split the dataset into train and validation sets
dataset = dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.2)
train_dataset = dataset['train']
val_dataset = dataset['test']

Print out dataset samples to ensure correctness
print(train_dataset[0])
print(val_dataset[0])
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf')

Add a pad token if it's not already present
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '\[PAD\]'})

Add a padding token to the tokenizer
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

def tokenize_function(examples):
return tokenizer(examples\['text'\], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=128)

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

train_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=\['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'label'\])
val_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=\['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'label'\])

Check dataset sizes and formats
print(f"Train dataset size: {len(train_dataset)}")
print(f"Validation dataset size: {len(val_dataset)}")

from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import bitsandbytes as bnb
from peft import get_peft_model, LoraConfig, TaskType

Determine the number of labels (classes) in your dataset
NUM_LABELS = len(df\['label'\].unique())

Load the pre-trained model with quantization
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', num_labels=NUM_LABELS, load_in_8bit=True, device_map='auto')

Apply QLoRA
peft_config = LoraConfig(
task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS,
inference_mode=False,
r=8,
lora_alpha=16,
lora_dropout=0.1,
)

model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)

from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments


Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
output_dir='./results',
eval_strategy='epoch',  # Use the correct key
learning_rate=2e-5,
per_device_train_batch_size=1,
per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
num_train_epochs=3,
weight_decay=0.01,
)

Create the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
model=model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=train_dataset,
eval_dataset=val_dataset,
)

Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()

Evaluate the model
trainer.evaluate()


